# How to combine several API calls to create single response object using RxJava

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm building an application which consists of two API calls. I'm still learning RxJava and I'm not sure how to combine properly the two API calls

1. The first API call is used to retrieve items in form of a list
2. The second API call is used to retrieve item image using the item name that I got from the first call.

I need to show all the items with their images. Those are my API calls using retrofit

```
@GET("items/list")
fun getItems(): Observable<ItemResult>

@GET("item/{name}/images")
fun getItemDetails(@Path("name") name: String): Observable<ItemDetails>
```

This is the code that wrote with RxJava:

```
    fun getItemsData(): Observable<ArrayList<ItemDetails>> {

    val data = ArrayList<ItemDetails>()
getItems().flatMap { itemResponse -> Observable.just(itemResponse.message) } //this will give me a list with item names
        .flatMapIterable { data -> data }//iterating over the list and for every item...
        .map { itemName ->//calling to get the item image
            getItemDetails(itemName).map { imageData ->
                val itemImage = imageData.message
                data.add(ItemData(itemName, itemImage))//from this point on I'm lost, I'm not sure if it's the right thing to add here the data
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    return Observable.create(data)// not sure how to create an Observable from the data
}
```

Comment: what do you want to return from `getItemsData`? `ItemData` or `ItemDetails`? `Observable<>` or `Single<List<>>`?

Comment: The inner stream in the outer map isn't even getting subscribed to. This won't work.

Comment: @AndreiTanana, Ideally I want to return Observable<ArrayList<ItemDetails>>. I could observe it later in my viewmodel and update the ui accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need this...

```
val data = ArrayList<ItemDetails>()
```

`flatMap` is not the right operator here:

```
flatMap { itemResponse -> Observable.just(itemResponse.message) }
```

you can simplify this by using `map` instead (the function `itemResponse -> itemResponse.message` operates on the inner value only).

```
map { itemResponse -> itemResponse.message }
```

Next:

```
.flatMapIterable { data -> data } // here we have Observable<Message>
.flatMap { itemName ->
     getItemDetails(itemName).map { imageData ->
        ItemData(itemName, imageData)
     }
 } // Observable<ItemData>
.toList() // Single<List<ItemData>> -> you can use toObservable to get an Observable<List<ItemData>>
```

You can use `toList()` instead of manually creating and populating the `ArrayList`, it simplifies things.

Comment: I still have an issue with the return type, which is my return type is now Single<ArrayList<ItemData>> and what the compiler found is Single<(Mutable) List<ItemData!>!>!

Comment: you can use `map { ArrayList(it) }` to go from `List` to `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the flat mapped stream to return the desired type -

```
getItems()
.flatMap(item -> getItemDetails(item)
                 .map(itemDetail -> ItemData(item, itemDetail.image))
.subscribe(itemData -> // your desired type containing the original item and image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not subscribing to the inner-stream inside the map. Try this:

```
val data = ArrayList<ItemDetails>()
    getItems().flatMap { itemResponse -> Observable.just(itemResponse.message) } //this will give me a list with item names
            .flatMapIterable { data -> data }//iterating over the list and for every item...
            .flatmap(itemName -> getItemDetails(itemName).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(itemDetail -> {//add to the list)})
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    return Observable.fromIterable(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to return an `Observable<ArrayList<ItemDetails>>`, may be you could use `reduce`?

Something like that:

```
fun getItemsData(): Observable<ArrayList<ItemDetails>> {
   return
     getItems().flatMap { itemResponse -> Observable.just(itemResponse.message) }
               .flatMapIterable { data -> data }
               .flatMap { itemName -> getItemDetails(itemName)  }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .map { imageData -> ItemData(itemName, imageData.message) } }
               .reduce(ArrayList<ItemDetails>(), (list, item) -> list.add(item))
               .toObservable()   
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

I am not sure about the right syntax of `reduce` in Kotlin...